# Response.redirect() is not a function in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect to another page after I receive a response from the post fetch, but as the title says it doesn't work.

These are the functions:

```js
// send/post json
async function postData(json_data, api_path) {
    const response = await fetch(api_path, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: json_data,
        redirect: 'follow'
    });
    console.log("postData response: ", response);
    return response;
}

// send JSON data to server on /api/${destination}
function saveSettings(form, destination) {
    let json_data = toJSONstring(form);
    let res;
    console.log(json_data);
    postData(json_data, `/api/${destination}`)
        .then((response) => {
            res = response;
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error, status = ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.text();
        }).then(text => {
            if (destination === 'network/post') {
                connected = false;
                updatingToast(`You are no longer connected to the device !`, false);
                updatingToast(`Please navigate to ${text}`, true, text);
            }
            console.log('res: ', res);
            res.redirect(res.status, res.url);
        });
}
```

Every `console.log();` returns `Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://192.168.0.100/dashboard', redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

If I place `response.redirect(response.status, response.url);` in the first `then()` I get the same error.

So, does [response.redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect) exist in Vanilla JS ?

I don't want to use `window.location.href` or any other similar option because it bypasses HTTP Authentication header.

Comment: Isn't it a static method? In any case, I don't think it does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the 'follow' argument given in the fetch.

You can check the if the response is being redirected using the code below. If it was not redirected you can simply change the window location and also force a redirect.

```
if (res.redirected) {
    window.location.href = res.url;
}
```

EDIT:

After doing a bit more research into the redirect method I saw that you need to switch the URL and status variables, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect

Comment: I don't want to use `window.location.href` or any other similar option because it bypasses HTTP Authentication header.

Comment: I see, I have updated my answer

Comment: Thats because the spec says: `var response = Response.redirect(url, status);` So you need to use `if (res.redirected) {  res.redirect(res.url, 301); }` Also you need to check if it has not redirected so `if (!res.redirected)`

Comment: `if (!res.redirected) { res.redirect(res.url, 301); }` does not redirect. Even though `res.url` appear in the network tab as a get request.